# Iterating over each timestamp in MongoDB collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, loops, sorting, timestamp

I have a nested array in the collection and each element of the array has a timestamp. The idea is to substract times for each sequential document to know if the time dfference is more than certain number.

I have added the index to the array but not sure how the function should look like.

The array is like this:

```
"data" : [ {"Event": ...,
"Timestamp" : ...},
...
{"Event": ...,
"Timestamp" : ...}]
```

After substraction the condition would apply (to see if the timediff is satisfying the condition).

Comment: Is this something that you want to do in application code, or with a mongo aggregation? Are you trying to do this for a single object?

Comment: I am trying to do this for a lot of objects. The method can be either aggregate or smth through pymongo, doesn't really matter